# How do I include Boost.Interprocess and Boost.DateTime properly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, boost-interprocess

This is a really basic question because I am a C++ newbie. I want to use the `Boost.Interprocess` library, but am having trouble building it. I'm trying to follow [these instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess.html#interprocess.intro.introduction_building_interprocess), but it's not working for me. Here is what I have:

```
#define BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB

#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, beautiful world!\n";
}
```

But I get this error:

```
boost_1_55_0\boost\date_time\gregorian_calendar.hpp(63) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp': No such file or directory
```

I know Boost is able to load properly, because I can get an example that uses `#include  <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>` to work just fine. It's just when I try to include the Boost.Interprocess library that I am having trouble. The cause is clearly because it's having trouble including the `Boost.DateTime` library properly, but according to the documentation (linked above) I should be able to get by without separately compiling `Boost.DateTime` if I define `BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB`, right?

What am I missing here?

Comment: show how you call the compiler (options, include path etc)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and I am just using the "Build Solution" (F7) command. The only change I made to the project's properties was to add to its "Additional Include Directories" the path to Boost, "$(SolutionDir)\lib\boost_1_55_0". Like I said, I know that this include is working properly because I was able to get a different example that used Boost to build and run properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to the preprocessor

In VS go to - Project >> properties >> C/C++ >> Preprocessor  in the 'Preprocessor Definitions' paste BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB.

Answer (score 0):

You can download boost libraries here: https://www.boost.org/users/download/
After that, you can include them in your projects. Also, you can check this video on how to add boost libraries in eclipse IDE on Ubuntu: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gN8zrnWxFeI